# Passing the data from a POST API request to lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, post, aws-lambda

I needed help with an issue that I am facing in order to meet the below requirement:

Requirement:
1. Submit form data from an HTML form through POST method to API gateway to a lambda function. One of the parameters in the email address.
2. Pass the parameters from the POST request to the lambda function. Lambda function should send out an email to the recipient via SES

Issue:
I am able to hit the lambda function via POST call, but I am not able to pass the variables.

Test case:
For testing the functionality, I have hardcoded the recipient address so that I get an email whenever the lambda function is hit. I am trying to pass the 'name' parameter and have the body of the email respond - Hi 'name'. Currently, I get the response- Hi undefined.

Below is the code I am using

```js
// Copyright 2019 Amazon.com, Inc. or its affiliates. All Rights Reserved.
// SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
var aws = require('aws-sdk');
var ses = new aws.SES({ region: 'us-west-2' });

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
  const emailbody = JSON.parse(event.body)
  var params = {
    Destination: {
      ToAddresses: 
    },
    Message: {
      Body: {
        Text: {
          Data: "Hi" + JSON.stringify(emailbody.name)
        }
      },
      Subject: {
        Data: "Test Email from lambda"
      }
    },
    Source: "myemailaddress@domain.com"
  };

  ses.sendEmail(params, function (err, data) {
    callback(null, { err: err, data: data });
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      context.fail(err);
    } else {
      console.log(data);
      context.succeed(event);
```

Reference: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-send-email-ses/

I tried to pass the variable directly via event.name as well, but I wasn't successful in inserting the variable.

```js
// Copyright 2019 Amazon.com, Inc. or its affiliates. All Rights Reserved.
// SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
var aws = require('aws-sdk');
var ses = new aws.SES({ region: 'ap-south-1' });

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
//  const emailbody = JSON.parse(event.body);
  var params = {
    Destination: {
      ToAddresses: ["test@recipient.com"]
    },
    Message: {
      Body: {
        Text: {
          Data: "Hi" + JSON.stringify(event.name)
        }
      },
      Subject: {
        Data: "Test Email from lambda"
      }
    },
    Source: "test@sender.com"
  };

  ses.sendEmail(params, function (err, data) {
    callback(null, { err: err, data: data });
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      context.fail(err);
    } else {
      console.log(data);
      context.succeed(event);
        }
    });
};
```

I am very new to the development and API world. Any help would be appreciated :)

Event Body

```js
{"Accept":"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9","Accept-Encoding":"gzip, deflate, br","Accept-Language":"en-US,en;q=0.9","cache-control":"max-age=0","CloudFront-Forwarded-Proto":"https","CloudFront-Is-Desktop-Viewer":"true","CloudFront-Is-Mobile-Viewer":"false","CloudFront-Is-SmartTV-Viewer":"false","CloudFront-Is-Tablet-Viewer":"false","CloudFront-Viewer-Country":"JP","content-type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded","Host":"8x4r6h1ko3.execute-api.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com","origin":"null","sec-fetch-mode":"navigate","sec-fetch-site":"cross-site","sec-fetch-user":"?1","upgrade-insecure-requests":"1","User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.88 Safari/537.36","Via":"2.0 1eaa44d3cb0c85af04bf84d0f0c5256f.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)","X-Amz-Cf-Id":"z5idar1dflmmUP7OeYfF6lc70fTpb9_hOeZHjDaNkVKVyy31tB8u_Q==","X-Amzn-Trace-Id":"Root=1-5e173941-6ad68db372cf676f8268bfa7","X-Forwarded-For":"126.51.226.203, 64.252.167.136","X-Forwarded-Port":"443","X-Forwarded-Proto":"https"},"multiValueHeaders":{"Accept":["text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9"],"Accept-Encoding":["gzip, deflate, br"],"Accept-Language":["en-US,en;q=0.9"],"cache-control":["max-age=0"],"CloudFront-Forwarded-Proto":["https"],"CloudFront-Is-Desktop-Viewer":["true"],"CloudFront-Is-Mobile-Viewer":["false"],"CloudFront-Is-SmartTV-Viewer":["false"],"CloudFront-Is-Tablet-Viewer":["false"],"CloudFront-Viewer-Country":["JP"],"content-type":["application/x-www-form-urlencoded"],"Host":["8x4r6h1ko3.execute-api.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com"],"origin":["null"],"sec-fetch-mode":["navigate"],"sec-fetch-site":["cross-site"],"sec-fetch-user":["?1"],"upgrade-insecure-requests":["1"],"User-Agent":["Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.88 Safari/537.36"],"Via":["2.0 1eaa44d3cb0c85af04bf84d0f0c5256f.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)"],"X-Amz-Cf-Id":["z5idar1dflmmUP7OeYfF6lc70fTpb9_hOeZHjDaNkVKVyy31tB8u_Q=="],"X-Amzn-Trace-Id":["Root=1-5e173941-6ad68db372cf676f8268bfa7"],"X-Forwarded-For":["126.51.226.203, 64.252.167.136"],"X-Forwarded-Port":["443"],"X-Forwarded-Proto":["https"]},"queryStringParameters":null,"multiValueQueryStringParameters":null,"pathParameters":null,"stageVariables":null,"requestContext":{"resourceId":"mmrduj26lk","resourcePath":"/","httpMethod":"POST","extendedRequestId":"GCXiOG99BcwFkdA=","requestTime":"09/Jan/2020:14:31:29 +0000","path":"/POST_Dev_Test","accountId":"856365680740","protocol":"HTTP/1.1","stage":"POST_Dev_Test","domainPrefix":"8x4r6h1ko3","requestTimeEpoch":1578580289353,"requestId":"010988e0-4598-4e88-af41-de42fa0b607e","identity":{"cognitoIdentityPoolId":null,"accountId":null,"cognitoIdentityId":null,"caller":null,"sourceIp":"126.51.226.203","principalOrgId":null,"accessKey":null,"cognitoAuthenticationType":null,"cognitoAuthenticationProvider":null,"userArn":null,"userAgent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.88 Safari/537.36","user":null},"domainName":"8x4r6h1ko3.execute-api.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com","apiId":"8x4r6h1ko3"},"body":"name=Tera&email=aditya.prakash%40psyora.com","isBase64Encoded":false}
```

Warm Regards,
Adi

Comment: how are you testing this lambda, via Api Gateway console , postman app, or curl?

Comment: I would like to see the input that you are passing

Comment: Thanks for the response @ArunK. At the moment, I am testing via API Gateway Console- The body I am passing in is -
{
    "name" : "PostTest"
}

Comment: have you attached the body.  i cant see. also are you using Lambda Proxy integration.

Comment: @ArunK yes, I am using the Lambda Proxy integration. I had attached the body of the event to emaildata variable. And, I just added my another code snippet where I am passing the variable directly as event.variable

Comment: can you log the `console.log('event.body: ', event.body);  console.log('type of event.body', typeOf event.body)

Comment: i want to see how the event.body looks like, and whether it is received a string. thanks

Comment: Hi @ArunK, please find the event body:

Comment: I only see a `-`

Comment: Sorry, I am trying to figure out how to post the long string.

Comment: @ArunK, I added the event body in the question. Sorry it hasn't been properly formatted.
What I find is - the payload is being sent as body:key=value. I am not sure how to extract it into a JSON string

Comment: Got it, posted my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have is a query string. The query is string is where you pass the value as `key=value&key2=value2`

- When you test it from API gateway, you should add the query strings under the section called `Query Strings` instead of `Request Body`

  - In your case the query string is:

    ```
    name=Tera&email=aditya.prakash%40psyora.com
    ```
  - You should access it inside the lambda as `event. queryStringParameters.name`:
- Your `event.body` contains the value `name=Tera&email=aditya.prakash%40psyora.com` which means your form is posted as `x-www-form-urlencoded`. Thats the type of form submission from html forms, therefore in your case, you need to decode the encoded string in your lambda.

  ```
  const qs = require('querystring')

  exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    const parsedQueryString = qs.parse(event.body)
    const name = parsedQueryString.name
  }
  ```

Hope this helps.

Comment: updated: changed `query` to `queryStringParameters`

Comment: Please `event.queryStringParameters` will be available if you pass the query string as `Query Strings` parameter when you test from api gateway

Comment: Arun, Thank you! I will try that. 
Can you share me some resources through which I can modify my html to send the data as query strings (or headers) for POST request?
Currently my form is pretty simple, below is the sample
<form URL="", id="", Method=POST>

Comment: how does your form currently sends the data, whats the format

Comment: Glad to be of help